# Insert [,] string array into a excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a [,] string array that is 40 rows by 40 column items. I am trying to write them into an excel sheet but the output keeps writing the same word on the first row of every column. What am I doing wrong?

```
   public static void writeToFile(this string [,] result)
    {

        try
        {
            //open instance of excel 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = null;


            app = new Excel.Application();
            app.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel._Worksheet sheet = app.ActiveSheet;

            sheet.Name = "Sheet 1";
            int resultCount = result.Length;


                for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++ )
                    {

                        sheet.Cells[i].Value = result[i,j];
                        j++;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
```

Comment: `sheet.Cells[i, j].Value = result[i,j];`   It's not clear why you're using `i++` and `j++` within your loops - you don't need that.  Also - indexes passed to `Cells[]` should begin at 1: there's no `Cells[0, 0]`, the first cell on the sheet is `Cells[1, 1]`

Answer (score 1):

If you got an array with rows at first dimension and columns at second dimension, you can simply write:

```
sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[1,1], sheet.Cells[40,40]].Value = result;
```